# Ant Design select tag no data rename

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, select, antd

I am using Ant Design select tag, when there is no data available it says 'No Data', is there a way to change that text to something else for example that 'No Data' rename to something else ?

here is example code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Select } from 'antd';

const { Option } = Select;

function onChange(value) {
  console.log(`selected ${value}`);
}

function onBlur() {
  console.log('blur');
}

function onFocus() {
  console.log('focus');
}

function onSearch(val) {
  console.log('search:', val);
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select
    showSearch
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    placeholder="Select a person"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    onChange={onChange}
    onFocus={onFocus}
    onBlur={onBlur}
    onSearch={onSearch}
    filterOption={(input, option) =>
      option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    }
  >
   
  </Select>,
  document.getElementById('container'),
);
```

Comment: I have [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67021486/1762224) the recommended solution that has been suggested by the Ant Design devs.

Comment: If you have questions regarding anything other than setting the empty text, then accept my response and ask another question in regards to disabling (when there is no data) the `<Select>` component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `notFoundContent` property will work, but it's a legacy property (still supported).

```
<Select notFoundContent="No people avaialable"></Select>
```

There is a closed GitHub ticket ([#23064](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/23064)) that explains workarounds and the correct way. You need to wrap your `<App>` or the component in question i.e. `<Select>` with a `<ConfigProvider>` and set the
`renderEmpty` prop function. The [API](https://ant.design/components/config-provider/#API) explains the usage of `renderEmpty`.

| Property | Description | Type | Default | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| renderEmpty | Set empty content of components. Ref Empty | function(componentName: string): ReactNode | - |  |

```
import { ConfigProvider, Select } from "antd";

// ...

<ConfigProvider renderEmpty={() => "No people avaialable"}>
  <Select></Select>
</ConfigProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the property `notFoundContent`

Information on how to use it can be found in the ant design select API documentation under the title:

> Select props

https://ant.design/components/select/#API

Here is an example of how it can be used:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Select
    showSearch
    style={{ width: 200 }}
    placeholder="Select a person"
    optionFilterProp="children"
    onChange={onChange}
    onFocus={onFocus}
    onBlur={onBlur}
    onSearch={onSearch}
    filterOption={(input, option) =>
      option.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    }


    notFoundContent={"Something Else"}


  >
    <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
    <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
    <Option value="tom">Tom</Option>
  </Select>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

A working example can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gtuzeh?file=index.js

Comment: Not recommended, it is a legacy property and may not be supported in future versions. :)

Comment: is it possible to have this '    notFoundContent={"Something Else"}
'  in the place '    placeholder="Select a person"
' when there is not data available ? and also user shoudnt be able to click and have dropdown when there is no data available

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl - Thank you, after some research I found this a thread on the matter : https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/23064

Comment: @walee - Well, in the case of the placeholder you will have to control that with a variable somewhere in your component. As for the user not being able to click on the dropdown due to no data being available you will have to disable the select in cases where there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

You can render component.

```
<Select notFoundContent={<div>No Data</div>}></Select>
```